# ubuntu server can't connect to internet or use sudo after power outage

Tags: networking, server, sudo

my power went out recently and when it came back on, I'm not longer able to connect to the internet from my ubuntu server.  I can still ssh into the server remotely from my laptop while I'm on my home network, but I can't ping anything from my ubuntu server once I've ssh in.  I've run the commands below, and I also have their output.  And just to make things interesting, sudo has also stopped working for me.  I've tried powering off and rebooting the server, powering my router on and off, changing the ports the ethernet is plugged into.  No luck connecting to the internet.  Does anyone have a suggestion what the issue might be, and how to fix it?

ping -c 4 google.com

```
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

nslookup google.com

```
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

ip addr

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:92:26:d9:d9:88 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.50.122/24 brd 192.168.50.255 scope global dynamic enp5s0
       valid_lft 73845sec preferred_lft 73845sec
    inet6 fdc5:79b0:1b6c:0:692:26ff:fed9:d988/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::692:26ff:fed9:d988/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip route

```
default via 192.168.50.1 dev enp5s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.50.122 metric 100 
192.168.50.0/24 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.50.122 
192.168.50.1 dev enp5s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.50.122 metric 100
```

route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.50.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp5s0
192.168.50.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp5s0
192.168.50.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 enp5s0
```